# What are the ramifications of the Hodge conjecture to mathematical physics?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, mp.mathematical-physics

I read a little bit the survey:
http://www.claymath.org/sites/default/files/hodge.pdf

Well I understand its a conjecture in Algebraic Geometry, so it seems there should be some consequences of proving this conjecture in mathematical physics.

So are there any? and what are they?

Thanks.

Comment: Here is a language question: If the Hodge conjecture is false, does it have any ramifications?

Comment: http://scienceworld.wolfram.com/physics/; i would start with 'every action has an equal and opposite reacton'

Answer (score 7):

There are connections to string theory as explained in [Open Strings and Extended Mirror Symmetry](http://www.math.mcgill.ca/walcher/papers/mfsdwalcher.pdf), by Johannes Walcher (2007). In one sentence: The Gromov-Witten theory of a Calabi-Yau manifold is solved by the Hodge theory of its mirror symmetric manifold.

A more elaborate quote from this 2011 [conference](https://www.birs.ca/events/2011/5-day-workshops/11w5090/press):

> The mathematical theory that describes how integrals and differential
>   equations control the shape of algebraic spaces in various dimensions
>   is known as Hodge theory. The most important conjecture in algebraic
>   geometry -- the Hodge Conjecture -- can be thought of as "a metaphor
>   for transforming transcendental computations into algebraic ones." The
>   physical theory able to describe the universe at both micro- (quantum
>   mechanics) and macro- (general relativity) scales, and at the same
>   time thought to be a suitable candidate for unifying all known forces
>   of nature, is string theory. There are several variants of this
>   "theory of everything," linked by dualities which can radically alter
>   mathematical formulations while preserving physical predictions.
>   String dualities thus imply conjectures: seemingly unrelated pieces of
>   mathematics must be related since they offer different descriptions of
>   the same physical world. Although a role for Hodge theory in string
>   theory has been hinted at for some time, only very recently has the
>   depth and precision of this relationship begun to emerge. Recent
>   results suggest that a mathematical "grand unification" relating
>   arithmetic geometry and symplectic geometry is taking shape.